# Julia - significance of f0 after a number

Tags: numbers, julia

What is the significance of `f0` in the following:

```
julia> 1.25f3

1250.0f0
```

What is the difference with `1.25 e3` which means `1.25 * 10^3` ?

I looked for in [the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/numbers/), but I did not find it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a very old manual you are reading, take a look at this section instead: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/ . The TL;DR is that with `f` you get `Float32` (single precision) and with `e` you get `Float64` (double precision):

```
julia> typeof(1.25f3)
Float32

julia> typeof(1.25e3)
Float64
```